# Magento theme Solwin-freego

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, custom-theme

I just upgrade[image] from magento default theme to Solwin-freego theme, everything seems to be ok except that my category section is not displayed correctly since the update to the new theme.

Comment: After upgrading to the freeGo theme. The "delivery on cash " option in payment methods in the backend is removed ? Does someone had the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below things once:

Solution 1 :

You need to have all your categories UNDER the "Default Category". Then they should show.

[image]

Solution 2 :

Verify that Default Category Is Active (Enable category = "yes") and "Include in Navigation Menu" to Yes.

[image]

Just go to the Stores -> All Stores -> Click on Store (Main website store) - >You will see Root category option there listed with your category name -> select that one -> click on save and check.

Clear cache by running the php bin/magento cache:clean command and check it will work.

Solution 3 :

Please check var/system.log,var/exception.log or browser console maybe you found some details.